# sending attachment fails with php mailer function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here I am trying to send email with an attachment, all codes are running fine but I didn't find any attachment along with the mail, but the same file is getting printed in hyper link that I had given with success message. I have used php mailer class in codeigniter.

```
public function sendmailto()
        {
        $this->load->library('phpmail');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $body             = "hello";

        $mail->AddReplyTo("reply@mymail.com","First Last");
    $mail->SetFrom('noname@mymail.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("mail@mymail.com","First Last");
    $address = "abcd@mymail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
 $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $mail->AddAttachment("../../uploads/a.pdf");      // attachment
   //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
 else {
         echo "Message sent!<a href='../../uploads/a.pdf' >click</a>"  ;  
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its path issue you can try this

```
$attachment = base_url().'/uploads/a.pdf';
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);      // attachment
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
$mail->MsgHTML();
```

to

```
$mail->Body;
```